# Set subquery results to array, takes too long to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a query that runs incredibly slow, and am trying to figure out how I can load the subquery into an array or something to make it faster.

```
SELECT COUNT(bdgid)
FROM member_badges
WHERE usid in(
    SELECT usid
    FROM member_badges
    WHERE bdgid in (1,4,5,6,7,8)
    GROUP BY usid
    HAVING COUNT(usid) =6)
GROUP BY bdgid
```

The subquery retuns a specific set list of usid's, and the main query counts the bdgid's that contain one of those user id's. But this example takes entirely too long to run.

```
mbrbdid    usid      bdgid
------------------------------
1            14        1
2            11        4
3            25        4
4            11        7
5            11        8
6            22        1
```

The table has over 30,0000 records. Basicly a usid can get any badge 1-10 one time each. This table is an instance of each time a user gets a badge. 
So I am trying to get all the usid's who have badge(1,4,5,6,7,8) and then do a count of each badge 1-10 but only using those specific id's

Comment: have you tried `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(bdgid).....`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `COUNT(DISTINCT bdgid)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT usid)`? Unless there are any nulls you have effectively written `COUNT(*)` in both cases.

Comment: Break down exactly what you want in words, then it will be easier to help. This is an incredibly confusing query.

Comment: Just added sample data,

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of users (who have the specified badges) for each badge? Or the number of badges that each user (who has the specified badges) has?

Comment: It should be a count of the badges, a group by bdgid to display bdgid 1,2,3,4,5..... then a count for each time that badge id shows up

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery is running for each row from the outer query you can rewrite you query by using a join with your subquery results as sub select,In this way sub select will be evaluated once and the result will get join with your outer query,Also an index for usid and bdgid will be helpful

```
SELECT COUNT(bdgid)
FROM member_badges a
join (
    SELECT usid
    FROM member_badges
    WHERE bdgid in (1,4,5,6,7,8)
    GROUP BY usid
    HAVING COUNT(usid) =6) b
on(a.usid = b.usid)
GROUP BY bdgid
```

Comment: I sort of understand what you are getting at, but this keeps returning an empty result set

Comment: @amazingacademy Can you provide some sample data set of your table with table definition ?

Comment: @amazingacademy your provided data set don't have bdgid 5,6 so for this data set query will return empty result set

Comment: it is just a sample, If i run just the subquery it returns over 1,400 results

Comment: @amazingacademy according to your comments i guess your are looking for the badge count [*See demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd4611/1)

Comment: +1 I tried to write my own answer, but came up with this as well.. I would however change the `COUNT(usid)` and `COUNT(bdgid)` to `COUNT(*)` otherwise it is just confusing. I'd also add the `bdgid` to the select columns.

Answer (score 1):

Split up the query using a temporary table and join against the temp table...

```
create temporary table usid_temp SELECT usid
FROM member_badges
WHERE bdgid in (1,4,5,6,7,8)
GROUP BY usid
HAVING COUNT(usid) =6
```

-- then join

```
SELECT COUNT(bdgid)
FROM member_badges a, usid_temp b
where a.usid = b.usid group by bdgid
```

I actually upvoted Khalids answer when I posted this because his is a better answer.

Comment: I have tried this, but once the table is created it doesn't add the data. I'm using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Don't do this, it's just a mangled copy of M Khalid's query.. you don't want to be creating a temporary table each time your run the query. Let MySQL do it for you with the join.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `EXISTS` instead of `IN` in this case.

```
SELECT COUNT(bdgid)
FROM member_badges A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT B.usid
    FROM member_badges B
    WHERE B.bdgid in (1,4,5,6,7,8)
    and A.UsID=B.usID
    GROUP BY B.usid
    HAVING COUNT(B.usid) =6)
GROUP BY bdgid
```